# Rearranging columns in table when using arcpy.CopyRows_management in ArcMap

Tags: python, arcpy, arcmap, fields-attributes

I am creating a table from a geodatabase using a fieldinfo object. I can create the table, but I need the columns to be in a specified order.  Is there a simple way to rearrange the column order before saving it as a .dbf file? Currently the columns come out as Miles, FType, FName
I need them to be FType, FName, Miles

```
    #Get the fields from the input

    fields2= arcpy.ListFields(InTable2)

    #Create a fieldinfo object
    fieldinfo2 = arcpy.FieldInfo()

    #Iterate through the fields and set them to fieldinfo2
    for field in fields2:

      #from near table calculation
        if field.name == "IN_FID":
            fieldinfo2.addField(field.name, field.name, "HIDDEN", "")
        elif field.name == "NEAR_FID":
            fieldinfo2.addField(field.name, field.name, "HIDDEN", "")
        elif field.name == "NEAR_DIST":
            fieldinfo2.addField(field.name, field.name, "HIDDEN", "")
        elif field.name == "NEAR_RANK":
            fieldinfo2.addField(field.name, field.name, "HIDDEN", "")
        elif field.name == "NEAR_ANGLE":
            fieldinfo2.addField(field.name, field.name, "HIDDEN", "")
              #From feature class   
        elif field.name == "FType":
            fieldinfo2.addField(field.name, field.name, "VISIBLE", "")
        elif field.name == "FName":
            fieldinfo2.addField(field.name, field.name, "VISIBLE", "")
        elif field.name == "Miles":
            fieldinfo2.addField(field.name, field.name, "VISIBLE", "")
        elif field.name == "Direction":
            fieldinfo2.addField(field.name, field.name, "HIDDEN", "")

    #Create the table with the fields listed above 

    arcpy.MakeTableView_management(InTable2, "FOC", "", "", fieldinfo2)


    #Append the data from all the other output tables 

    arcpy.management.Append(["output1","output2","output3"], "FOC", "NO_TEST")

    #Save table to DBF file 

    arcpy.CopyRows_management("FOC", mpars.replace("-","") + "Features_For_GWTool.dbf")
```

Comment: Within ArcGIS there's often multiple ways to do anything.  In this case, though, your requirement to change order probably limits the ability to use CopyRows, meaning you'll need to use nested DA SearchCursor/InsertCursor instead (or after).

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem is you are reordering the fields in a *TableView* and the Copy Rows in not honouring it?

Here is some code I had worked up a few years ago that reorders fields, note I'm using Table to Table tool to create the table

```py
inputTable = "ABC" # This is a table loaded into ArcMap
outputTable = "XYZ"
 
# Get field mappings of Input Table
fieldMappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()
fieldMappings.addTable(inputTable)
 
# Create an empty FieldMappings Object
newFieldMappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()
 
# Add fields in desired order. Note field index must be known
newFieldMappings.addFieldMap(fieldMappings.getFieldMap(3))
newFieldMappings.addFieldMap(fieldMappings.getFieldMap(0))
newFieldMappings.addFieldMap(fieldMappings.getFieldMap(2))
newFieldMappings.addFieldMap(fieldMappings.getFieldMap(1))
 
# Create Table
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(inputTable, "IN_MEMORY", outputTable, None, newFieldMappings)
```